# Why is a form element making my div take up more space than without it?

Tags: html, css, layout, semantic-ui

I have a menu bar on my site and I'm trying to add a search field. It's been on the site for a while but hasn't done anything yet. Here's what it looks like:

```css
body {
  margin: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.5/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.5/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui inverted menu">
  <a href="/" class="active item">
                Home
            </a>
  <div class="right item">
    <div class="ui inverted transparent input">
      <input type="text" name="pageName" placeholder="Navigate to...">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="ui black button">Go</button> </div>
</div>
```

I'm finally getting around to making it functional, so I added a form element around the search input and the button:

```css
body {
  margin: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.5/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.5/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui inverted menu">
  <a href="/" class="active item">
                Home
            </a>
  <div class="right item">
    <form id="navigateForm" action="/Page/NavigateForm" method="post">
      <div class="ui inverted transparent input">
        <input type="text" name="pageName" placeholder="Navigate to...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="ui black button">Go</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

But with the form element, the menu bar is taller than without it. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a form element, transform one `div` to `form`. The issue is due to the use of the `>` selector in some CSS rules which will break if you introduce an extra element so the rule will no more apply and you will get a new result.

Example:

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.5/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.5/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui inverted menu">
  <a href="/" class="active item">
                Home
            </a>
  <form id="navigateForm" class="right item" action="/Page/NavigateForm" method="post">
      <div class="ui inverted transparent input">
        <input type="text" name="pageName" placeholder="Navigate to...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="ui black button">Go</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem not with the form , it with the button class (class="ui black button")
you need to remove the padding top and bottom for it and style it as you like there is a lot ways to fix it

```css
body {
  margin: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.5/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.5/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui inverted menu">
  <a href="/" class="active item">
                Home
            </a>
  <div class="right item">
    <form id="navigateForm" action="/Page/NavigateForm" method="post">
      <div class="ui inverted transparent input">
        <input type="text" name="pageName" placeholder="Navigate to...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="" style="background: #000; color:#fff;font-weight:bold;border:none;padding:0px;">Go</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```